# How to insert a row into a table with a column is List from a select query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I am learning PostgreSQL, and need help to solve one problem.

I have two java entity classes, say

```
User 
{
   Long id;
   String name;
   Set<Long> bookIds;
}

Book
{
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

When it translated into PostgreSQL DB scheme, it created a user table, user_bookids table and book table.

I want to insert a new row into user table and user_bookids table with bookids selected ids from book table.

I knew how to do it in Java land, I can create a user object and populate the bookIds list and persist, data will be populated to two tables.

but how can I do this in PostgreSQL.

Thanks in advance for all helps.

Comment: do you want to create a element collection table `user_bookids`?

Comment: @Ramanlfc : yes, user_bookids table was there already.